# How to remove indexed URLs from google

Tags: indexing, content-management-system, search-engine, google-search-console

Problem : I installed X CMS in my website and its urls are indexed in google but later I removed that CMS and installed new CMS.

How can I remove earlier CMS indexed urls, they are huge in no like 70k+ ?

I have already search for noindex and google webmaster tool, but not sure what to use, every option has its own limitation.

Need your help.

Answer (score 0):

block them with **robots.txt** - more info: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Answer (score 0):

We have several options: 
either demote them via webmaster tools;
Configure urls in .httacces file
Write urls in robot.txt file